# Share and download links not working in facebook in-app mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have three links which generate an image and then share the image on a page or download the image directly.

Unfortunately none of these links are working in facebook in-app browser. They seem to work great in all other browsers I have tried. Is there something I can do to the code that is called on click?

I am guessing the two social links are not working somehow because of the "window.open" command? Should I somehow make it append as a link to the button on click?

Any help or direction is appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.facebook').click(function() {

            var path = new String(window.location);
            var resultPath = 'https://website.com/generator/share/?img=<?=$file?>';
            var fbpopup = window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?hashtag=%23hashtag&u=" + resultPath, "_blank", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=no");


        });    

        $('.twitter').click(function() { 
            var path = new String(window.location);
            var resultPath = 'https://website.com/generator/share/?img=<?=$file?>';
            var twShareLink = 'text=Check out my personalized image and create your own! %23hashtag &url=' + resultPath;
            var twpopup = window.open("http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?" + twShareLink , "_blank", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=no");
        }); 

        $('.download').click(function() {
            var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
            downloadLink.href = '<?=$url?>';
            downloadLink.download = 'image.jpg';
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            downloadLink.click();
            document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
        });   
});
```

Comment: It appears that the in-app browser doesn’t open new windows with window.open, but just opens the URL in the current window. I’d try with normal links with `target="_blank"` first. If that doesn’t work, you could try and stay in the same window - at least for the Facebook Share dialog, you can specify a redirect URI it should return to after the user is done sharing. Not sure if Twitter offers something similar, you’d have to check.

Comment: Whether triggering a download this way works at all in that browser, no clue. But if you just make that a normal link to `https://website.com/generator/share/?img=...` as well, it should work fine, if you make that script issue the appropriate headers to trigger a download as well.